# in mid-order -- grammar

Tags: grammar

Example:

> In the following sections, you’ll consider how to build better forms with some codepowered
>   features. The following forms are covered:
>   • PlaceOrder lets you create a new order. It works in conjunction with the PlaceOrder_
>   Subform, which lets you add individual items to the order.
>   • AddProduct lets you create a new product. You can use it directly from the
>   PlaceOrder form to add a product **in mid-order**.
>   • ShipOrders lets you update an order with shipment information. It also works
>   with a form named ReviewOrderDetails to show the items in the order.

How do you understand that phrase grammatically? I don't think I have ever seen that kind of phrase used before.

Comment: **[mid-](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mid_2)** "the middle of a period of time: used with many nouns". A similar phrase is "mid-air".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's example is a (*very* slightly creative) variant of the idiomatically commonplace [*in **mid-conversation***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20mid%20conversation%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (that's about 12,100 written instances in Google Books).

And *that's* modeled on the even more common [*[don't switch horses] **in midstream***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20mid-stream%2Cin%20midstream&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20mid%20-%20stream%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20midstream%3B%2Cc0)...

[image]

...which as you can see has become so well established we've done away with the hyphen.

In OP's case, *in mid-order* can be "expanded" to *in the middle of [the process of **creating/amending**] an order*. Taking another example, you might do/say something [*in the middle of [the process of] **striding***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20mid-stride%2Cin%20midstride&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20mid%20-%20stride%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20midstride%3B%2Cc0). As that last NGram shows, the idiomatic "device" has become far more popular in recent decades.

But I would caution learners not to be too enthusiastic about adopting this usage in *every* credible context. One particular issue is that although ***in*** works okay in OP's *exact* context, it's only "optional" (in that and many other contexts, native speakers often wouldn't include it).

---

TL;DR: The ***adverbial*** construction *[in] mid[-]**X*** means *[whilst] in the middle of **X***. Superficially ***X*** may be an "object" *(order, stream, conversation)*, but usually it's a shorthand way of representing a "process" *(**placing** an order, **crossing** a stream, **having** a conversation)*.